# jQuery event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, hyperlink

I have 3 files:

- js_json.js -> for my json code
- javascript.js -> for my javascript
  function
- index.php

Here the code for `js_json.js`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#postTitle').change(function(){

        var title_id = $("#postTitle").val();


        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"proses.php",
            data:"title_id=" + title_id,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                body="";
                //$.each(data, function(i,n){
                    //body = n['body'];    
                //});
                body += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"pesan\" name="pesan" onClick=\"\">Hola Test</a>";
                $(".postBody").empty();
                $(".postBody").append(body);
            },
            error:function(data){
                $(".postBody").empty();
                $(".postBody").append("NO Post Selected.");
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and here my `javascript.js` code:

```
$(function (){
    $("a[name=pesan]").click(function (){
        alert("holalalalalal.....!");    
    });
});
```

and here the `index.php` code:

```
    //some code
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="pesan" name="pesan">Hola Test 1</a>
        Posts : <br />
        <select name="title" id="postTitle">
            <option value="">Select Post...</option>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT id, title FROM posts ORDER BY title";
                $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    print('<option value="' . $rows['id'] . '">' . $rows['title'] . '</option>');
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br />
        Body : <br />
        <div class="postBody">
            Will show the body of post.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my question is:

When I click the link "Hola Test 1", it works and the message appears. The problem is, after I click the select option, and the link "Hola Test" appears, and then I click that ("Hola Test") link, the message does not appear and there are no errors in firebug...

Can somebody explain to me why...? Thank's...

Comment: Use `.live()` as [@Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173238/jquery-event-not-firing/6173263#6173263) answered, but keep in mind that it is invalid to use the same id in a page more than once (*ids are unique*), and will more than likely cause other problems in the future..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`click()` will only bind the event for elements that exist in the page at the time `click` is called (the same goes for `on()` without a selector, `bind()`, and all the other methods in the shortcut-group for bind; `keydown()`, `change()` etc. ).

Because your other element is getting added via AJAX *some time later*, the handler isn't bound for it.

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a selector instead, which will bind the event to all current and future elements matched by the selector.

```
$(function (){
    $(document).on('click', 'a[name=pesan]', function () {
        alert("holalalalalal.....!");    
    });
});
```

Since `on()` was introduced in jQuery 1.7, if you're using earlier versions of jQuery (like those that existed when this question was asked), you can use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) instead of on;

```
$(function (){
    $('a[name=pesan]').live('click', function () {
        alert("holalalalalal.....!");    
    });
});
```

Comment: thank's, it work...
and thank you for the explanation...
that's what I was looking for....

Comment: thanks for this! I got stuck before by using 'on' directly to the element like: $( "p" ).on( 'click', function() {} ); any explanation why? I noticed that Chrome is throwing this warning: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 2):

I want to mention *(because I found no mention of it in any of the "event not firing" cases I scoured the web for)* that there is a possibility which might bite you.

If you happen to use **[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)** to extract something temporarily from the DOM and then reinsert it, then you will lose your events.  What you need to use instead is **[.detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)** to preserve the data and events after reinsertion.  This can be hard to debug as everything may look normal, and the event debugging tools are sketchy at best.

*(Personally I would call them something more like **.detachAndScrubDataAndEvents()** and **.detach()**, as I'm a fan of descriptive names saving hours of debugging.  For those who find **.remove()** and **.detach()** to be semantically and meaningfully distinguished names... peace be with you... BUT you're flat out wrong.)*