# ajax post method unable to recieved data in php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

`forget.php` PHP:

```
if (! (empty($_POST['emailforget'])) ) {
    echo "here in the function";
} else {
    echo "here";
}
```

AJAX:

```
$("#passreset").on('click', function(e) {

  var emailforget = $("#tempemail").val();
  alert(emailforget);
  //ajax call here
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'user/forgetpass.php',
    data: {
      'emailforget': emailforget
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      //alert("here in function beforesent");
    },
    success: function(html) {
      //alert(html);
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = html;
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("alert error");
    }

  });

  return false;


});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="email" id="tempemail" name="tempemail" 
    placeholder="Enter your email address" value="ab.waseem@yahoo.com" required>
```

The code was working perfectly but suddenly stopped working.

Checking in Firefox and Chrome console gives no error.

The call is sent perfectly to the respective file.

Comment: Use your developer console (Chrome or FF) and click the "Networking" tab, then limit to "XHR" - that's your AJAX requests.  Trigger the AJAX call.  Inspect the call - is it 200? If so, what is the response back from the server? (This is all available in the developer console: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).  Does the call happen? If not, then is your jQuery in the `head` of the document? If so, the `passreset` element does not exist when the jQuery loads, so see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173238/jquery-event-not-firing

Comment: Could it be as simple as your URL pointing to `user/forgetpass.php` and your actual file being `forget.php`? (Inferred from your question meta information)

Comment: @cale_b yes ajax call is 200, but it's not passing the data ($_POST['emailforget']) alway's empty..

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery, things like this: `document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=html;` could become `$('#error').html(html);`....

Comment: What does the rest of your `<form>` look like?

Comment: @cale_b that suggestion makes no sense to me

Comment: @Jonathan Ajax call 200, I am getting the response from file, the issue is ($_POST['emailforget'])) alway's remain's null, data is not passing.

Comment: @Jonathan - I understand.  I just know that - I can't explain why, but when I created the object "on the fly" in the AJAX call, it did not work, but when I declared it explicitly BEFORE the ajax call, it did.  Just an idea!

Comment: @pmahomme reset of form is quite simple with a button

Comment: @cale_b yes alert(emailforget) contains the value

Comment: Change `data` to `data: { emailforget: $("#tempemail").val() },` please

Comment: @Jonathan still not works

Comment: @Jonathan - why would that change anything?

Comment: @cale_b it shouldn't. But by process of elimination there was something unsetting or failing to set the data property of the request. Grabbing directly without relying on any other prior assignment implied it was being broken some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `processData` being false. Just remove this option altogether and it should work. If this does not work, also remove `contentType`.

For more information read the documentation on the [options](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) carefully.

Setting `processData` to `false` implies sending the data in the form it was created. Set to true, it will process it into a query-string.

The default content type header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, and setting the content type to `false` likewise removes it entirely.

I would stay away from modifying these defaults unless you know exactly why you need to change it in the first place.

Comment: For more details on **why** changing processData will make the difference, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6253318/870729

Comment: @TalhaAslam you're welcome :) Please don't forget to accept the answer when the grace period expires~